# How do you access a common property of generic type inside a method in C# (using constraints?)

Tags: c#, generic-constraints

I have the same method that repeats in my project for different classes:

```
public Task DoSomething(Class1 class)
{
    // do stuff
    var commonProperty = class.commonProperty 
    // do stuff
}
```

And in a different service

```
public Task DoSomething(Class2 class)
{
    // do stuff
    var commonProperty = class.commonProperty 
    // do stuff
}
```

I have learnt that I can use generic types and believe this would be a good place to apply this - something like :

```
public Task DoSomething<T>(T class) 
{
    // do stuff
    var commonProperty = class.commonProperty 
    // do stuff
}
```

But I can't access the property as such and can't find how to add multiple options for constraints.

Comment: var commonPropert = ((object)class).GetType().GetProperty("Name of Property").GetValue(class, null);

Comment: No, this question is missing context. Because this sounds like a case where you should not simply merge unrelated classes. Yes DRY, but not always. Keep things separate (and simple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must create a hierarchy of objects:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public object CommonProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Class1 : BaseClass
{
}

public class Class2 : BaseClass
{
}
```

Then you can use the where [generic type constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) to specify the generic type:

```
public Task DoSomething<T>(T class) where T : BaseClass
{
    // do stuff
    var commonProperty = class.commonProperty 
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: No, i don't think this is good. Adding inheritance makes things unnecessarily complex. And breaks the single responsibility principle. Kiss: Keep it simple ...... IMHO this question is missing any context to give a good fitting answer.

Comment: i already have a base class  but i created an interface and inherited that my classes